# K-Prototypes in python "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Tags: python, k-means, categorical-data

I am trying to perform a k-prototype clustering to mixed data(categorical and numeric). My input file is a csv which looks like this(it contains 300000 rows):

```
  Unnamed: 0.1,market,vendor_name,price,ship_from,category_cl
   0,mark,03welle,1.79367196,DE,Drugs
   1,aruna,03welle,0.05880975,DE,Drugs
   2,ny,03welle,0.11344859,DE,Drugs
   3,mi,03welle,0.18655316,DE,Drugs
```

I am trying to implement a k-prototypes clustering as can cluster mixed data. The problem is I am getting an error and I cannot understand it(and of course fix it). I am using the code I found in the relative repo:

```
import numpy as np
print("initialising")
syms = np.genfromtxt('pameteliko.csv', dtype=str, delimiter='\t')[:, 0]
print("******")
print(syms)
X = np.genfromtxt('pameteliko.csv', dtype=object, delimiter='\t')[:, 1:]
print("################")
X[:, 0] = X[:, 0].astype(float)
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes
kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=6, init='Cao', verbose=2)
clusters = kproto.fit_predict(X, categorical=[1, 2])

#Print cluster centroids of the trained model.
print(kproto.cluster_centroids_)
#Print training statistics
print(kproto.cost_)
print(kproto.n_iter_)
```

(The prints are there for debugging purposes). I am getting the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I have also some doubts regarding the `syms` and the `X`. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem you are getting from Array slicing in syms, it returning a list of array that shape (300001,) and you are trying to get zeroth row so it return out of index error, when you check syms.shape

Comment: Or if its csv file the delimiters should be ',' not '\t' Try to change delimiter = ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change delimiter '\t' to ','

```
syms = np.genfromtxt('pameteliko.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',')[:, 0]
print("******")
print(syms)
X = np.genfromtxt('pameteliko.csv', dtype=object, delimiter=',')[:, 1:]
```

because you are using comma-separated value files. I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you, it was the delimeter causing the problem.